# How to fill a DataTable with XElement/XAttribute?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I'm new to C#, I never worked with a DataTable before.

I want a DataGridView with specific names.

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        List<string> bla = new List<string>();

        XDocument config = XDocument.Load(configFile);

        Dictionary<string, string> dict = config.Descendants("Columns").FirstOrDefault().Elements()
            .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("XPath"), y => (string)y.Attribute("Name"))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        //I dont know if I need this:
        foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(key, typeof(string));
        }


        foreach (XElement position in positions.Where(e => e.HasAttributes))
        {
            foreach (XAttribute attribute in position.Attributes().Where(a => dict.ContainsKey($"@{a.Name.LocalName}")))
            {
                string name = attribute.Name.LocalName;
                string value = (string)attribute;
                string xName = dict["@" + name];

                bla.Add(xName);
            }
```

The columns should have the name from **xName.**

How can I do this?

I've tried this:

```
            foreach (var item in bla)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                row.SetField<string>(item); //this didn't work.

                //foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
                //{
                //    row.SetField<string>(key, item[key]);
                //}
            }
```

Just want the names from **xName** as my heading for the output.

Example für xName: Position, Status, Order, Number, ...
As my heading.
And under that the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, you've got your list of column names ok, but dont know how to create a datatable with the correct column names.

Below is an example of how to add a column and row to a datatable with a specific column header name.

As discussed in the comments, I've demonstrated a process to get the data you need into a structure that allows you to populate your table.

```
      //Class to hold data
  public class MyRecordContent
  {
        public MyRecordContent()
        {
            //initialise list
            RecordsColumns = new List<string>();
        }

        //Holds a list of strings for each column of the record.
        //It starts at position 0 to however many columns you have
        public List<string> RecordsColumns { get; set; }
  }

            //This creates an empty table with the columns
            var myTable = new DataTable("Table1");
            foreach (var item in bla)
            {
                if (!myTable.Columns.Contains(item))
                {
                    myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(item, typeof(string)));
                }
            }



         //Here you build up a list of all records and their field content from your xml.
        foreach (var xmlNode in yourXMLRecordCollection)
        {
            var thisRecord = new MyRecordContent();

            foreach (var xmlCol in xmlNode.Elements)//Each column value
            {
                thisRecord.RecordsColumns.Add(xmlCol.GetValue());
            }

            myListOfRecords.Add(thisRecord);
        }

        foreach (MyRecordContent record in myListOfRecords)
        {
            var row = myTable.NewRow();

            //Here we set each row column values in the datatable.
            //Map each rows column value to be the value in the list at same position.
            for (var colPosition = 0; colPosition <= myTable.Columns.Count - 1;) //Number of columns added.
            {
                row[colPosition] = record.RecordsColumns[colPosition];
            }

            myTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

In the above, itterate through your list of column names and add each column to the table. You may want to add a switch statement to the loop to change the datatype of the column based upon name if required. Then create of new row off that table and set each fields value accordingly.
Finally, add the new row to the datatable.

Hope that helps.

Then

Comment: Ah thank you! Yeah I don't know how to create a datatable with the correct column names..
But for the `"MyColumnName"` I should take `item` or not?
Otherwise it says "Column ‘.....’ does not belong to table" ?

Comment: @Lizzy - Yes. If item is your string column name, then replace "MyColumnName" with item.

Comment: Allright. And whats with the `"FieldValue"`? What does this say?
And the other problem: I have more **xName** with the same name, but different values.. so it say "column already exists". ?

Comment: @Lizzy - "FieldValue" was showing you how to set the value of the column for the current row. So replace that text with what ever should be in the that field. Ideally, you need to create a unique list of column names to prevent the duplicates. But you can check so I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that works!! :) So in `row[heading] = "FieldValue";` I have to put the `value` from the other foreach.. in here. But I have no access to that value. Ehm.. How do I do that.. ?

Comment: Where are your row column values stored? Are they in the XML doc as well?

Comment: Yeah, they are in the XML doc as well. And I have them all in the `string value`. Just want these under the headings.

Comment: Without seeing your XML is hard to visualize your data structure. You need to get all the data from your XML doc and store it in a list of objects that contain all your required fields data. Then for each object in the list you add a new row and set the field value from the properties in the object. I'll add to the post.

Comment: OK. I've edited my post. This is just to help you with the idea of how to get the data from your xml doc to your datatable. The syntax is not correct, you will have to work out the xml bit... but the concept should be sound.

Comment: But I don't know what to write in the `row["Field1"] = record.Field1;` at the "Field1" ?

Comment: @Lizzy - "Field1"  Should be the 1st column name of the data table you created. then you add a second line to set the 2nd column. row["Column2"] = record.Field2 etc.... I should have used the word "Column" not "Field" in my answer. But i dont know what your columns are called which is why I said "field"

Comment: Yeah, but the names can always change.. So I can't just say a specific name for the columns. Because the name should be always the name from the **xName**. It can say "Position" or "Number" or "Status". It always say "the column xxx doesn't belong to the table"

Comment: @Lizzy - Use a column index then instead. row[0], row[1]

Comment: ahh, okay, and if I have 8 columns, I need to write row[0], row[1], ... row[7]?
But what if I can always have a different amount of columns? Or does this doesn't care?

Comment: Yes. row[7] etc..  If you have a changing number of columns then you could always put the setting of row value into a loop. So you get row[X] = value.... where X is a var counting up to the number of columns in your datatable.    myTable.Columns.Count!

Comment: So, now somewhere is a mistake haha.. Now my output is, that all the right names are as headings over the columns. Thats good :D
But now in the first column, are standing all the names of the columns again. And in the second, there are all the values.
So but I don't need all the names in the first columns, because those are my headings.. In the last foreach I just need the values?

Comment: Yes.. in the last foreach you are setting the column (field) values of each row. Not the column name of the datatable.

Comment: Okay, so I don't need the class anymore or? Can you give me an example for a changing number of columns.. ?

Comment: @Lizzy - Hello. Keep the class. That holds each records data. I've updated my answer to show what I mean. Hope that helps